# How to override ChannelSftp.lstat method so that to return false instead of SftpException in Jsch

Tags: java, jsch

The current definition of `ChannelSftp.lstat` is as below.

```
public SftpATTRS lstat(String path) throws SftpException {
        try {
            ((MyPipedInputStream)this.io_in).updateReadSide();
            path = this.remoteAbsolutePath(path);
            path = this.isUnique(path);
            return this._lstat(path);
        } catch (Exception var3) {
            if (var3 instanceof SftpException) {
                throw (SftpException)var3;
            } else if (var3 instanceof Throwable) {
                throw new SftpException(4, "", var3);
            } else {
                throw new SftpException(4, "");
            }
        }
    }

private SftpATTRS _lstat(String path) throws SftpException {
        try {
            this.sendLSTAT(Util.str2byte(path, this.fEncoding));
            ChannelSftp.Header header = new ChannelSftp.Header();
            header = this.header(this.buf, header);
            int length = header.length;
            int type = header.type;
            this.fill(this.buf, length);
            if (type != 105) {
                if (type == 101) {
                    int i = this.buf.getInt();
                    this.throwStatusError(this.buf, i);
                }

                throw new SftpException(4, "");
            } else {
                SftpATTRS attr = SftpATTRS.getATTR(this.buf);
                return attr;
            }
        } catch (Exception var6) {
            if (var6 instanceof SftpException) {
                throw (SftpException)var6;
            } else if (var6 instanceof Throwable) {
                throw new SftpException(4, "", var6);
            } else {
                throw new SftpException(4, "");
            }
        }
    }
```

Since I am very new to java world , I would like to know how we can override `ChannelSftp.lstat` method so that to return false if a file does not exist (`ChannelSftp.SSH_FX_NO_SUCH_FILE`) and in all other cases (for all exceptions other than file not exist) to throw `SftpException` itself.

Comment: You can't. you can create a method that does this, but it won't be an overriden version of this method

Comment: Create a method in a new class??

Comment: if you want to override something, it always has to be in another class (a subclass), but since you can't do what you want with an override, an overload would be an option, and that can be both in another or in the same class